# C, structures, simple example protests syntax UPDATED

Tags: c, structure

UPDATED:

I found the bug, single quotes wrong. Replaced it by double quotes and worked fine. Sorry for the inconvenience but caught it soon.

===========================================================================

This is a simple example of what should be a structure declaration and access to its data, but I get a list of errors complaining that the "character constant is too long for its type" and also "passing of argument 1 in printf makes pointer from integer without a cast". So, the program crashes with overflow stuff. Nombre is first name, apellido is last name, and edad is age. Was trying to gather all that in a structure and the print the results accessing them through a pointer. (Why do I have to access them through a pointer and not simply by the dot notation?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct estructura_amigo {
 char nombre[30];
 char apellido[40];
 char telefono[10];
 int edad;
 };
struct estructura_amigo amigo = {
 'Juanjo',
 'Lopez',
 '592-0483',
 30
 };
struct estructura_amigo *p_amigo;
int main()
 {
 p_amigo = &amigo;
 printf( '%s tiene ', p_amigo->apellido );
 printf( '%i años ',  p_amigo->edad );
 printf( 'y su teléfono es el %s.\n' ,  p_amigo->telefono );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes, like this

```
printf( "%s tiene ", p_amigo->apellido );
```

In C single quote = char, double quote = string.

And

```
printf( "%s tiene " , amigo.apellido );
```

should work, no need to get a pointer to the struct.